# How do i change the Cursor.lockState to be unlocked?

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

In the Start function i did:

```
void  Start (){

        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }
```

This make the cursor locked and to not be visiable.

Now i added to the Update function:

```
void Update(){

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Confined;
    }
```

So if i click on Escape it will release the cursor back and will shot it.
But it's not working does nothing. I tried Confined i also tried None but it's not doing anything the cursor still locked.

I used a break point and it's getting to this line to the Confined but the cursor is still locked.

Answer (score 0):

This is working in the Update function i did:

```
void Update(){

        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Escape)) {

            if (Cursor.lockState != CursorLockMode.Confined) {

            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Confined;
            Cursor.visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because (for some reason) you must transition. http://answers.unity.com/answers/1119750/view.html